# Angular change multiple files to inline template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a couple Angular components spread out over multiple files, created using `ng generate`.

Some components have inline styles, since the html/styles can be quite small so it makes sense to use inline templates here.

[image]

The issue is that I'd like to translate a couple of these 'multi-file' components to inline styles - is there a way to do this within the Angular ecosystem?

Comment: The Angular CLI command ng generate component defines an empty styles array when you create the component with the --inline-style flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go in `.ts` file of the component and inside of the `@Component` decorator change the `templateUrl` to `template`, and `styleUrls` to `styles`. Then you can delete `.html` and `.scss` files and transfer their code in `.ts` file.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-component',
  template: `<div>Your component inline HTML.</div>`,
  styles: ['div { text-align: center; }']
})
```

If you want to generate a component with inline templates and styles, you can do that with passing `--inlineTemplate=true --inlineStyle=true` option to the CLI when generating the component:

```
ng generate component custom-component --inlineTemplate=true --inlineStyle=true
```

Comment: Hiya - thanks for explaining.  You don't know of any tooling/commands that could do this automatically?

Comment: Create new inline components or replace existing non-inline to inline?

Comment: replace existing non-inline to inline?

Comment: No that I know.